# Importing a downloaded JAR file into a Servlet

Tags: json, jsp, servlets, jar, import

I have recently downloaded the json-lib jar, and added it to my libraries using NetBean's library wizard.

I believe to import net.sf.json.JSONObject, I first have to call the package at the beginning of the servlet file.

However, when I try to do 'package net.sf.json', I get the error 'class, interface or enum expected'.

I have placed the jar in the WEB-INF/lib folder. I am certain I'm missing something, but I'm not certain what. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: 'Call the package' is meaningless. You don't have to be inside a package to use a class from that package, if it's intended for public use. You haven't provided the source code, but this is just a trivial syntax error.

Comment: It looks like you're confusing `package` with `import`. I suggest to take a pause on developing Java EE web applications, take a step back, and spend a bit more time learning Java SE. Compilation errors namely indicate a very basic Java problem.